# GitHub Pages Images not loading when added to new page

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Okay, so I'm currently updating my github pages site to have several pages, instead of all my info being on the home page. I created new .md files and used the yaml front matter to set the title, layout, and permalink of the new page. I then copied over my markdown "code" from my index.md file to my new .md file, without changing anything. The markdown in question includes a few html lines to insert images.

For some reason, the images are loading properly on the page connected to index.md, but not on any of my new .md pages. I know it's not a case-sensitivity issue, and my new .md files are in the same directory as index.md, so its not like there's a pathing issue.

Any ideas?????

For your reference:

Homepage: http://www.catherineslaughter.space/

New page in question: http://www.catherineslaughter.space/research/

Repo: https://github.com/catieslaughts/catieslaughts.github.io

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in the 'research' folder you want to go up a level. Try `../images_pdfs/SURFfinalPoster.jpg` as an example for any image you link to on your research page.

Currently your relative path images are resolving to: `http://www.catherineslaughter.space/research/images_pdfs/SURFfinalPoster.jpg`

instead of

`http://www.catherineslaughter.space/images_pdfs/SURFfinalPoster.jpg`